# Postgres: Get sum based on list in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, locations like this:

| location | sub_locations |
| --- | --- |
| A | A,a1,a2,a3 |
| B | B,b1,b3 |

and another table, hours like this

| location | hours |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| a1 | 1 |
| a1 | 1 |
| b3 | 8 |

for each location, I need to get the total hours for the sub_locations.

The result I'm looking for is this:

| location | sub_locations | total_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A,a1,a2,a3 | 8 |
| B | B,b1,b3 | 11 |

I can simply get the sum for the location with a simple join and group by location, but what I need is the total hours for all the sub locations. I've explored using another select statement for the total_hours column, but just got an empty result.

```
select 
l.location,
l.sub_locations,
sum(h.hours::float) as "sum plan hours for location"
from 
locations l 
join
hours h 
on l.location = h.location 
group by l.location,l.sub_locations
```

Comment: Storing comma separated values is a huge mistake to begin with.

Comment: Your `Locations` table doesn't even comply with first-normal form, fix this any everything becomes easier.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the table to create a one to many relationship, and the query became a lot easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dreaded comma separated string into an array and use that in a JOIN condition:

```
select l.location, l.sub_locations, sum(h.hours)
from locations  l 
 join hours h on h.location = any(string_to_array(l.sub_locations, ','))
group by l.location, l.sub_locations;
```

---

A better solution would be to fix your data model and create a proper one-to-many relationship that doesn't store locations/sub-locations in a CSV column.

Comment: fixed table to one to many relationship instead. a simple group by query did the job after this

Answer (score 0):

I think think this will do the work for you, or if not tell me the result, so I can write again with more information.

```
  select  
    l.location,
    l.sub_locations,
    sum(h.hours::float) as "sum plan hours for location"
    from 
    locations l 
    join
    hours h 
    on l.location = h.location 
    WHERE h.location In (select sub_locations from locations where location = 'Your Location value(ex-A)')
    group by l.location,l.sub_locations
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Didn't get around to try this, as decided to amend the locations table instead. This made the rest a lot simpler